# Is there a way to use @media queries with pages embedded into Facebook?

Tags: css, facebook

Would a @media query recognize the 520px Facebook iframe limitation?

Comment: Easy to test, surely?

Comment: If the integration was already setup, then yes. I was just wondering if someone knew off the top of their head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - at least, with Chromium 9.0.597.107 (75357) Ubuntu 10.04.

It took me five minutes to knock together [a quick test case](http://www.cheddarmonk.org/iframetest/wrapper.html). Feel free to check it in as many browsers as you can.

Comment: Does this solution work or not?